# Work on list of tuples in Scala - part 2

Tags: scala, list, pattern-matching, tuples

I'm new to Scala, and trying to understand how to work on lists of tuples, so I've created a fictive list of people:

```
val fichier : List[(String, Int)] = List(("Emma Jacobs",21), ("Mabelle Bradley",53), ("Mable Burton",47), ("Ronnie Walton",41), ("Bill Morton",36), ("Georgia Bates",30), ("Jesse Caldwell",46), ("Jeffery Wolfe",50), ("Roy Norris",18), ("Ella Gonzalez",48))
```

I'd like **to code myself** a function that sorts ascendantly this list, by age:

```
  def classeur(personne: List[(String, Int)]) : List[(String, Int)] = 
  personne match {

    case (name1, age1) :: (name2, age2) :: t if age1 <= age2 => { (name1, age1) :: (name2, age2) :: classeur (t ) }
    case (name1, age1) :: (name2, age2) :: t if age2 < age1 => { (name2, age2) :: (name1, age1) :: classeur (t ) }
    case x => x

  }
```

But it sorts the tuples pair by pair instead of taking the biggest one (in age) and compare it to the next tuple.

What am I doint wrong?

Comment: It works for me. You sure you get the exact same list?

Comment: What do you mean by _nothing happens_? I think your algorithm won't sort the list properly, it just gets two elements and reorder them but not against the whole list.

Comment: @KevinHoerr I edited my topic. it does not return the exact same list but sorts the tuples two by two

Comment: @nicodp right. Any suggestion to fix this, regardless to sortBy method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to code a sorting algorithm on your own, I'd recommend reading about different implementations in [Sorting algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm).

But for the sake of playing with this, we can implement `mergesort` in `Scala` as follows:

```
def merge(firstHalf: List[(String, Int)], secondHalf: List[(String, Int)]): List[(String, Int)] = firstHalf match {
  case Nil => secondHalf
  case x::xs => secondHalf match {
    case Nil => firstHalf
    case y::ys => if (x._2 < y._2) x::merge(xs, secondHalf) else y::merge(firstHalf, ys)
  } 
}

def classeur(personne: List[(String, Int)]) : List[(String, Int)] = 
  personne match {
    case Nil => Nil
    case List(x) => List(x)
    case _ => {
      val (firstHalf, secondHalf) = personne.splitAt(personne.length / 2)
      merge(classeur(firstHalf), classeur(secondHalf))
    }
  }
```

And you'll get:

```
scala> classeur(fichier)
res0: List[(String, Int)] = List((Roy Norris,18), (Emma Jacobs,21), (Georgia Bates,30), (Bill Morton,36), (Ronnie Walton,41), (Jesse Caldwell,46), (Mable Burton,47), (Ella Gonzalez,48), (Jeffery Wolfe,50), (Mabelle Bradley,53))
```

Nevertheless, I'd recommend you to look at @Tom's answer, as you should use the `Scala` predefined sorting algorithms whenever you can.

Comment: Ok, this is a little bit complicated for me so I will save your answer and look at it again soon when my level in Scala gets better. Thank you

Comment: If you read how `mergesort` works you will see the algorithm depicted in my code, this is pretty much basic Scala, just a couple of pattern matching definitions and recursive calls.

Comment: hello. I've read about the merge-sort algorithms and tried to understand what you did to sort the list and added comments to your code. Can you please, have a look at them and tell me if I'm on the right way?

Comment: @Yuva just commented on it with an explanation

Answer (score 1):

It is not returning the exact same. If you change the people's names to numbers from 1 to 10 you can see that it returns `1, 2, 4, 3, 6, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10` which is original list but with `3` and `4` swapped places, and `5` and `6` swapped places.

And this is what you code does, it goes through the list and looks at each pair of elements, and orders them. I.e., if your input list was in descending order, the result would be `2, 1, 4, 3, 6, 5, 8, 7, 10, 9`.
If you want to sort it without pattern matching, you can use `sortBy`:

`fichier.sortBy(f => f._2)`

Or more concisely:

`fichier.sortBy(_._2)`

Comment: I thought this algorithm would take the pairs this way: `(1 and 2) then (2 and 3), ..., (9 and 10). I know i can use sortyBy but wanted to write my own function

Comment: Not quite, if you want to do it that way, your recursive calls to `classeur` would need to include the previous element, e.g. `{ (name1, age1) :: classeur((name2, age2) :: t) }`
But this still wouldn't sort the list for any input.

Comment: I also think it's worth saying that for any comparison sort algorithm, the best time complexity you can get is `O(nlog(n))`. In other words, you cannot design a comparison sort algorithm that sorts any list with one pass.

Comment: `you cannot design a comparison sort algorithm that sorts any list with one pass.` ok. I will keep that in my mind.

Answer (score 0):

In principle, we aren't interested in the whole name-thingy and could first try to sort on our own with simple numbers:

```
  def classeur (ages: List[Int]) : List[Int] = ages match {
      case age1 :: age2 :: t if age1 <= age2 => { age1 :: age2 :: classeur (t)) }
      case age1 :: age2 :: t if age1 > age2 => { age2 :: age1 :: classeur (t)) }
    case x => x
  }
```

It's the same problem, only simpler described. :)

So for a list of ages (11, 22, 33, 24, 45, 6)

- we compare 11, 22 and return, after classeuring the rest, 11, 22
- we compare 33 24 and return (11, 22 (24, 33 (cl (r))
- we compare 45 6 and return (11, 22, 24, 33, 6 45)

Instead, we could push the loser to the sorting part:

```
  def classeur (ages: List[Int]) : List[Int] = ages match {
      case age1 :: age2 :: t if age1 <= age2 => { age1 :: classeur (age2 :: t)) }
      case age1 :: age2 :: t if age1 > age2 => { age2 :: classeur (age 1:: t)) }
    case x => x
  }
```

But that doesn't solve the whole problem:

For our list of ages (11, 22, 33, 24, 45, 6)

- we compare 11, 22 and return (11  cl(22 :: r))
- we compare 22, 33 and return (11 22  cl(33 :: r))
- we compare 33, 24 and return (11 22 24  cl(33 :: r))
- we compare 33, 45 and return (11 22 24 33  cl(45 :: r)
- we compare 45,  6 and return (11 22 24 33 6 45)

a slight improvement, but it only pushed the biggest number to the end, and swapped (33, 24).

The whole idea doesn't look very promising. :)

Instead, you could pull the minimum out of the list, and proceed recurively. This is pseudocode:

```
  def classeur (ages: List[Int]) : List[Int] = {
      val min = ages.minimum
      val rest = ages.without (minimum) 
      min :: classeur (rest) 
  }
```